# function call rect for roi

Tags: c++, opencv, roi

```
    Mat img1 = imread("hello.jpg", 1);
    Mat img2(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC3);

    img1(Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)).copyTo(img2);
```

I am learning opencv using c++.

but I don't understand the syntax that img1(Rect()). From my understanding, for function call, it should like img1.rect().

Any terminlogy for a object with ()?   here is img1(xxxxxx);

Comment: It is overloaded function call operator. [`Mat Mat::operator()(const Rect& roi)`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6) (I didn't came up with more contents to post as answer...)

Answer (score 2):

I do not know opencv, but that looks like a `operator()` call. Some operators can be overloaded, and `operator()` is one of them:

```
struct foo {
    void operator() {
        std::cout << "hello world";
    }
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    f();     // calls operator() and prints "hello world"
}
```

And indeed, if we look at [opencv documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) we can find:

> ```
> Mat   operator() (const Rect &roi) const
> ```

PS: Actually objects with `operator()` are rather common. Consider for example a lambda:

```
auto bar = [](){ std::cout << "hello world"; };
bar();                                           // prints "hello world"
```

Its a callable, an object with an `operator()`.